# iOS: get informed about a started animation on a UIView and the animation end

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I wanted to know if there is a way to get informed that an animation has started on an UIView and ended. Like a delegate method (didBeginAnimating or something).

I know that I can check for animationkeys on a views layer, but that is not what I want. I need to turn off layer shadows when an animation began and on again when the animation is over. The problem is that this animation is called from another Object that doesn't know about this object.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

there is delegate method called `+ (void)setAnimationWillStartSelector:(SEL)selector` 
(From UIView Class Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationWillStartSelector:)

This is what you wanted?

Comment: Nope since this is only a way to define a method that should be send to the animationDelegate on animationstart. I can't set my object as delegate since the other object doesn't know about it.

Comment: so how the object making animation in the other object without knowing about it?

Comment: it is animating a superview which has a childview which has this view as it's childview ^^

Comment: `[super animatingStarted];` ?

Comment: [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            [(MGSplitViewController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController setSplitPosition:mode];
        } completion:nil]; and the rootviewcontroller has subviews which have subviews.

Comment: there is no method called animatingStarted and like I said I need to use a listener and not query myself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39288/discussion-between-caro-and-theshay)